# Rendering Layouts without loading its inner layout in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to bring a layout in my html page by

```
render layout 'flatty'
```

thing is this loads the whole `flatty` layout. In `flatty.html.erb` it renders `_header`,`_footer` and also `_sidebar.html.erb`
I dont want to load `_sidebar.html.erb` in this particular page. 
So how should i render this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in your controller action, you can have a flag indicating the sidebar should not be rendered. Then, in your `flatty.html.erb` file, check for the flag variable before you render the `_sidebar.html.erb`.

For example, if you have a controller action called `flatty`, add an instance variable, `@disable_sidebar`, to act as your flag.

```
def flatty
  @disable_sidebar = true
  # Your other code
  render layout: 'flatty'
end
```

Then, in your `flatty.html.erb`, add a conditional before your `render` for your sidebar (note the `!` negation in the `if` statement:

```
<% if !@disable_sidebar %>
  <%= render "layouts/sidebar" %>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, in your `flatty.html.erb` you can also check for the `controller` and `action` values in your `params` hash, and then don't render your sidebar if it matches that controller's action:

```
<% if params[:controller]!="YOUR_CONTROLLER" and !params[:action].eql? "flatty" %>
  <%= render "layouts/sidebar" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: rails 4 provides controller_name and action_name helpers so you don't need to check for params or even better separate it out in some partial and render in both cases

Answer (score 3):

> thing is this loads the whole flatty layout. In flatty.html.erb it renders _header,_footer and also _sidebar.html.erb I dont want to load _sidebar.html.erb in this particular page

*Why do you want to use same layout if you have so many changes? **Why not make a partial which you could render in both cases. Make a new partial, lets say _common.html.erb, render it in your flatty layout and view of the action in which you want to use it.***

```
#flatty.html.erb
<%= render "common" %>
<%= render "sidebar" %>

#some_action_name.html.erb
<%= render "common" %>
```

---

If you still want to use same layout in both cases then you ca use rails 4 [**`controller_name`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class) and [**`action_name`**](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActionController/Base:action_name) helpers in your layout and selectively render sidebar and other partials in your layout:

```
 #flatty.html.erb
<%= if controller_name == "some_controller_name" && action_name == "some_action_name"
  <%= render "sidebar" %>
<% end %>
```